# How we can set the font for all applications according to selected font type in one application

Tags: android

Suppose I have an "apk" file. In this app, we can set the font. My question is how we can set that selected font for all applications.

Comment: You cant apply selected font in one application in another one except if you can the help of database which is going to be share by other applications.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the question?

Comment: For example we set the time through time and disply taht time all applications take time from that like this i want to set the font

Answer (score 2):

You can't. What would be the point of me being able to define fonts in my application if you were going to override them?